# What "storing records unviolated to have multiple downstream benefits." means in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What do "unviolated to have multiple downstream benefits" mean in this context?

> Healthcare, education, and entertainment are the sectors with the highest potential for Blockchain in India.
>
> For example Blockchain can help create a distributed-ledger solution that is future-forward, secure, and scalable, for effective deployment of government programmes and drug distribution.
>
> In education, Blockchain could become useful in storing educational **records unviolated to have multiple downstream benefits**.

source: http://lovelymobile.news/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Blockchain_Playbook_Final.pdf

I have never imagined "unviolated" means "as received" or "intact" in this context.
I thought "unviolated" should be related to laws, restrictions, etc.
Also, I didn't know the usage of "downstream", which mean "something that happens later in a process or series of events".
I thought "downstream" should be related to river or stream.
Moreover, the expressions like "downstream benefit" are bit difficult to understand for me, non-native speaker. 
The expressions like "you can get benefits as time passes" are easy to understand for me.

Comment: Where are you getting these quotes? Please read our [_Details, please_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) along with [_Why you should cite your source_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). Then, please edit your questions to tell us where you are finding these quotes about Blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: storing educational records unviolated.

This simply means that educational records are stored in the 'as received' condition, so without any post-processing. Of course, in reality, some processing is always required simply to allow certain kinds of data to be stored, but presumably they are not referring to such.

Second: to have multiple downstream benefits.

Because they have stored the files in an 'as-received' condition, rather than in a summarised form for example, the raw data is available for processing at any point down the river of time. This is important, because some data cannot be processed very well at the time of storage. Later, with better processing available, the old data becomes a valuable resource, in ways that could not be conceived when it was stored.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Blockchain could become useful in storing educational records unviolated to have multiple downstream benefits.

If we parse **to have multiple downstream benefits** as complementing **unviolated**, and take the infinitive clause there as a statement of purpose, the full clause could be paraphrased:

*Blockchain could become useful in storing educational records unviolated so that they may have multiple downstream benefits.*

There, **unviolated** would mean "intact, in their original form, that is, not summarized or aggregated such that the data would lose their granularity".

I do not know for certain what "future-forward" means. It's a neologism. I suppose it means "forward-looking".

Answer (score 0):

> In education, Blockchain could become useful in storing educational records unviolated to have multiple downstream benefits.

let me paraphrase it according to my perception:

In education, Blockchain could become useful in storing educational records **intact** *so that we can get* multiple **prospective** benefits.

It's necessary to mention that I used the preceding answers but I tried to add some facilitative features.